# Header may not contain NUL bytes Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, hyperlink, header

when I do a redirect with *Header Location* function in PHP or *redirect* codeigniter function the browser returns this error:

> Header may not contain NUL bytes

How I resolve it?

I'm using codeigniter framework

```
$link=$this->model->str_decrypt($_GET['crplinK'], KEY_CRYPT);
$id=$this->model->str_decrypt($_GET['aInsD'], KEY_CRYPT);
$link = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $link);
$link=str_replace('www.', '', $link);
$url = prep_url($link);
if($this->db->query("UPDATE ".SCHEMA.".ads SET clicks=clicks+1 where id_ads=".$id))
 redirect($url, 'refresh');
else echo pg_last_error();
```

where `$link="http://nokia.it";`

Comment: What is `str_decrypt`?  Maybe the decoded string still has some padding on it (like NUL characters). What does `var_dump($url)` print?

Comment: $link="http://nokia.it";

Answer (score 0):

try to `var_dump($your_url);` to see if it contains some UGLY characters.. If so,then **`TRIM()`** it before calling.